# \\n appears as \n in an input tags -- using htmlspecialchars() on user input

Tags: php, input, heredoc, htmlspecialchars

I have a simple issue -- the user fills out a form and when the form is POST'd I store the data into a HEREDOC and save that to a file that can be opened and viewed in the browser.

The problem is I can't figure out how to get the user's typed text input 100% faithfully re-displayed within an html 'input' tag.

Here's an example of my **troublesome user input**:

```
 oh' mesquid"ly b\\n;"'
```

When I open the file to redisplay that bit of data, it fails because of the quoting:

```
    <input type="text" id="theSubject" value='oh' mesquid\"ly b\\n;\"''/>
```

All I see in this input field is  **oh**

So I tried **htmlspecialchars()** -- and that gets me *almost* there -- but I lose one of the 2 backslashes before the 'n' in my sample text string, and the output looks like
**oh' mesquid"ly b\n;"'**

Here's the code -- 'myTitle' here got filled with the above **oh' mesquid"ly b\n;"'** by me, the user, I typed it into the form then POST'd the form  (and as I preview this question here, I notice that the StackOverflow post text input has the same problem -- despite the fact that I typed in two "\" backslashes in the 1st line of this paragraph, as I view my question here before submitting it I note that one of the backslashes is missing, sorry about that, out of my control):

```
 <?php

   $title = $_POST['myTitle'];
   $theEscapedTitle = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES);

   $html = <<<HEREDOC

   <?php
      \$title = '$theEscapedTitle';   
   ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
      <input type="text" id="theSubject"value='<?php echo $title ?>'/>
   </body>
   </html>  

   HEREDOC;

   file_put_contents("myFile.php", $html);

 ?>
```

When I open  "myFile.php", the above 'input' tag looks like this:

```
    <input type="text" id="theSubject" value='oh&#039; mesquid&quot;ly b\n;&quot;&#039;'/>
```

Why am I losing one of the 2 backslashes in my input text string 
**oh' mesquid"ly b\n;"'** and what should I do to *faithfully* reproduce the text string?

**EDIT**

I got a workable solution below and had to tweak it a bit, here's the solution to my problem:

```
 function reproduceBackslashesFaithfully($string) 
 {
      $string = str_replace('\\','\\\\',$string);
      $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
      return $string;
 }
```

When I pass this function my user's input containing doubled backslashes, I now see those double backslashes faithfully reproduced in my **input** tag in my code above.  I'm looking into why the original 'pass by reference' of the function parameter given in the answer by Anonymous below did not work for me, as the PHP docs indicate that pass-by-reference function parameters should work in my PHP version 5.3.5.

Comment: why is it going into a file?

Comment: @Dagon -- the web site takes user input and saves it out to a file that they can view later, like a note taker, sort of.  A user types in any type of text input they want, then we create a web page they can open later in the browser.

Comment: Not a good idea. Write real content to the file, not a PHP script.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- I've been viewing my outputted files in my Netbeans development environment which shows **no** PHP code in the output disk file -- but after your comment I thought to use a plain text editor, not the Netbeans editor, to view the file -- wow there is raw PHP in the disk file!  For some reason, the Netbeans editor doesn't display that.  What's my hazard?, and thanks for the tip, kinda new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should double the backslashes and fix the apostrophes as well:

```
<?php
    function clean(&$string) {
        $string = str_replace('\\','\\\\',$string);
        $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
?>
```

And you can easily implement it by using `clean($var)`

Comment: that worked but I had to modify it -- for whatever reason, the 'pass by reference' ampersand in the function's parameter is not working, phpinfo tells me I have an old 5.3.5 version of PHP here, not sure if that's why -- I am adding your slightly modified version to my original question above -- thanks, it works.